# Rope wrapped around pole Friction

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A rope is wrapped $M$ whole turns round a cylindrical post, the two ends of the rope
going in opposite directions. The coefficient of friction between rope and post is $0.25$. It is
desired that by pulling with a force of $1N$ on one end of the rope, I can prevent the rope
from moving away from me even if a force of $10^6N$ is applied to the other end. How large
does M have to be? (Note that to 3 significant figures, $ln(10^6) = 13.8$).
Hint: Let the tension in the rope decline like $T(\theta)$ with the angle  round the pole.
Investigate $T(\theta + \theta _0 ) − T(\theta).$

What topic does this come under, is it rigid body rotation or something else? Also what is the function for Tension the question seems to be implying to differentiate?

Comment: Nope. The topic is "force" and "friction"; many first-year physics books have something very similar to this as an example. I'm pretty sure that the Berkeley Physics Series' book on Mechanics does, for instance.

Comment: Okay, I'll add a few.

Comment: At every small part the rope is in balance if the difference of forces at the part's ends is equal to the force of friction at the place. And the friction is proportional to the force pressing the rope to the pole surface, which results form the tension. So yes, it's going to be a differential equation, kind of $dT/d\theta = const\cdot T(\theta)$ with a given value of $T$ at the working end of a rope. You need to find such $M$ that $T(M\cdot 2\pi)$, that does not exceed your 'stoppig' force.

Comment: See [Frictional force on a rope wrapped around a drum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/58112).